# .NET Fill HTML Helper TextBox from Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I had a look around and couldn't find a clear answer for this so it may be helpful to others too! I'm trying to prepopulate a text box with a viewbag variable select here:

```
ViewBag.contactemail = db.Identifiers.Where(c => c.ID == id).First().contact;
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("toemail", new { @ViewBag.contactemail }, new { @class = "form-control" })
<p>@ViewBag.contactemail</p>
```

The paragraph shows the email only :

> Katie@gmail.co.uk

however the Text box appears like this

> { contactemail = katie@gmail.co.uk}

ive tried putting it in quotes, or placeholder = as other people have suggested, or in theory removing the brackets, and even the new part as they appear in the placeholder content but I can't see to get it to show just the email?

Comment: What you should be doing is assigning the value to the `toemail` property and just using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.toemail, new { @class = "form-control" })` so that you get proper strong typed model binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the value in an object:

```
@Html.TextBox("toemail", ViewData["contactemail"], new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this earlier and got this error: CS1973: 'HtmlHelper<EmailAccount>' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Strange - try casting the string to an object: @Html.TextBox("toemail", (object)@ViewBag.contactemail, new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Ignore that, just use ViewData, I've changed my answer.

Comment: that works perfectly, way too novice to have figured that out myself! Thanks :)